# Simplify the expression of binom

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Any one knows how to simplify this expression or finding upper bound of this expression:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} a^{j+i} {j+i \choose i}$$ where $0<a<1$ is constant.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $t$ also a constant?

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake. I just revise a problem

Comment: A trivial bound is given by $\frac{a}{(1-a)(1-2a)}$ (I have a proof if you want one) but the exact expression depends on the incomplete Beta function.

Comment: please show me the proof Jack D'Aurizio. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite it as:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} a^k\sum_{0\leq i<j\leq n+1}_{i+j=k} \binom{k}{i}\leq \sum_{k=1}^{2n+1}a^k \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{k} \binom{k}{i} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} (2a)^k =  a\frac{1-(2a)^{2n+1}}{1-2a}$$

When $a=\frac{1}{2}$ this upper bound is $\frac{2n+1}{2}$

This gives about the same bound as Jack's answer when $a$ is small, but a much better bound when $a$ is close to $1$.

Comment: it seems the upper bound is >1? is it right?

Comment: Not always greater than $1$ - if $a<1/3$, it is bounded above by $\frac{a}{1-2a}<1$.

Comment: FWIW I think you are premature to select my answer - there could easily be better upper bounds.

Comment: thank you so much, Thomas.

Comment: I have other question but no one knows the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879764/upper-bound-of-sum-m-12n11-2m-sum-j-m-2n1n1-choose-jn-c. Could you and some one help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a fixed $j$, we have:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}\binom{j+i}{i}x^i = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{j+1}}\tag{1}$$
hence the original sum is trivially bounded by:
$$\frac{1}{1-a}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\frac{a^j}{(1-a)^j}=\frac{\left(\frac{a}{1-a}\right)-\left(\frac{a}{1-a}\right)^{n+2}}{1-2a},\tag{2}$$
but obviously we included a lot of unnecessary terms in $(1)$. In order to make things more symmetric, we may consider that:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}a^{i+j}\binom{i+j}{i}=\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\sum_{i<j}a^{i+j}\binom{i+j}{i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}a^{i+j}\binom{i+j}{i}-\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}a^{2k}\binom{2k}{k}\right)$$
due to the symmetry of the binomial coefficient $\binom{i+j}{i}=\binom{i+j}{j}$. Now, assuming $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a^{2k}\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4a^2}},$$
and:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k>(n+1)}a^{2k}\binom{2k}{k}&=&\sum_{k>(n+1)}\frac{a^{2k}}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+e^{i\theta})^{2k}e^{-ki\theta}\,d\theta\\&=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{(a^2(2+2\cos\theta))^{n+2}}{1-a^2(2+2\cos\theta)}d\theta\\&=&\frac{(2a)^{2n+4}}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{(\cos\theta)^{2n+4}}{1-4a^2\cos\theta}d\theta,\end{eqnarray*}$$
where the integral can be approximated by considering that the integrand function almost behaves like a normal distribution with zero mean, so:
$$\sum_{k>(n+1)}a^{2k}\binom{2k}{k}=(2a)^{2n+4}\cdot \Theta\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
[Continues]

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the last sentence about the difference. Could you please explain more?

Comment: I'll modify my answer in order to be more precise.

Comment: Thanks so much Jack. Even your answer is not simple to understand but I like it so much (still waiting for the continuation). It opens some other things that could be applied to other problems. Thanks again